# Incoming Call Stop Application - Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

Not long ago developed a system based on compact framework for Windows Mobile Professional 6.0 (C #), but when this system is running and the PDA receives some type of call, my application is terminated abruptly causing data loss and forcing the user to open again.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening? Or is there a way to keep the two functions in use without interfering in one another?

Comment: What? No love for the ladies of Stackoverflow?

Comment: I think I know your problem. You're developing for Win Mobile. There, I saved you countless hours of frustration.

Comment: @nmc It's weird how many people think SO is a boys-only club... Now edited, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most times, depending on the radio, cell tower and provider, a phone can only handle ONE connection, either a voice or a data connection.

Voice calls have a higher priority than data connections and so the data connection will be interrupted during the phone call.

You need to make your app either compatible with non-continues data connection or disable incoming call acception.

Possible further help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32200/Own-your-phone-Taking-back-control-of-your-mobile

Or you simply kill cprog.exe or replace it with a custom application

regards

Josef